# console errors even though code runs as expected, how to resolve undefined

Tags: javascript, object, runtime-error, console.log

I have a small issue which I haven't been able to resolve whatever I do. Anybody that knows about movie file notation will understand what I'm trying to do a lot easier but I will try to explain. I have a group of buttons that show a token and an example of the text if said token is used. These can be changed into default, lower or upper case, and/or have the words separated by space, dot(period), underscore or dash. There is a select element for each.

Selects:

```
<div class="grid" id="choosers">
    <div class="col no-margins full md-3 md-push-6">
        <div class="form-field">
            <div class="form-select small full-width">
                <select name="separators" id="separators">
                    <option value="0">Space ( )</option>
                    <option value="1">Dot (.)</option>
                    <option value="2">Underscore (_)</option>
                    <option value="3">Dash (-)</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col no-margins full md-3">
        <div class="form-field">
            <div class="form-select small full-width">
                <select name="case" id="case">
                    <option value="0">Default Case</option>
                    <option value="1">Lower Case</option>
                    <option value="2">Upper Case</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Buttons:

```
<div class="col no-margins full md-6">
    <div class="form-field">
        <button type="button" class="naming small button">
            <span class="flexible token">{Quality Title}</span>
            <span class="flexible example">BluRay 1080p</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col no-margins full md-6">
    <div class="form-field">
        <button type="button" class="naming small button">
            <span class="flexible token">{Release Year}</span>
            <span class="flexible example">2017</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

There's 20 buttons in all.
So, I have a javascript object to make things simpler so that I can import it directly, with all of the possible outcomes, split up by separator and then case, so it goes:

```
let naming = {
    space: {
        default: [
            {
                token: "{Quality Title}",
                example: "BluRay 1080p"
            },
            {
                token: "{Release Year}",
                example: "2017"
            }
        ],
        lower: [
            {
                token: "{quality title}",
                example: "bluray 1080p"
            },
            {
                token: "{release year}",
                example: "2017"
            }
        ],
        upper: [
            {
                token: "{QUALITY TITLE}",
                example: "BLURAY 1080P"
            },
            {
                token: "{RELEASE YEAR}",
                example: "2017"
            },
        ]
    }
};
```

etc, etc.

Then you have the javascript, with the call:

```
document.getElementById('choosers', chooserEvents, false);
```

and then the function:

```
const chooserEvents = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
        let clicked = e.target;

        if (clicked.matches('#case') || clicked.matches('#separators')) {
            let case = document.getElementById('case'),
                seps = document.getElementById('separators'),
                caseVal = case.options[case.selectedIndex].value,
                sepVal = seps.options[seps.selectedIndex].value,
                flexibleTokens = document.querySelectorAll('.flexible.tokens'),
                flexibleExamples = document.querySelectorAll('.flexible.examples'),
                data;

            switch(true) {
                case sepVal == 0 && caseVal == 0:
                    data = naming.space.default;
                break;
                case sepVal == 0 && caseVal == 1:
                    data = naming.space.lower;
                break;
                case sepVal == 0 && caseVal == 2:
                    data = naming.space.upper;
                break;
                case sepVal == 1 && caseVal == 0:
                    data = naming.dot.default;
                break;
                case sepVal == 1 && caseVal == 1:
                    data = naming.dot.lower;
                break;
                case sepVal == 1 && caseVal == 2:
                    data = naming.dot.upper;
                break;
                case sepVal == 2 && caseVal == 0:
                    data = naming.underscore.default;
                break;
                case sepVal == 2 && caseVal == 1:
                    data = naming.underscore.lower;
                break;
                case sepVal == 2 && caseVal == 2:
                    data = naming.underscore.upper;
                break;
                case sepVal == 3 && caseVal == 0:
                    data = naming.dash.default;
                break;
                case sepVal == 3 && caseVal == 1:
                    data = naming.dash.lower;
                break;
                case sepVal ==3 && caseVal == 2:
                    data = naming.dash.upper;
                break;
            }

            let size = data.length;
            for (let i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
                flexibleTokens[i].innerText = data[i].token;
                flexibleExamples[i].innerText = data[i].example;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

So you're probably wondering what's wrong, it all seems to be correct, and that's what I thought, especially as it works exactly as I wanted it to. But with this code I receive a console error of: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined. So I tried to code it in different ways. I first took the for statement and pasted one in each switch case so that the object notation string could be as a whole. Same error! I then did 2 short switch statements. Same error!
After a lot of research I found a webpage [short-circuiting with &&](https://css-tricks.com/%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8Bavoiding-those-dang-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-errors/#short-circuiting-with). I tried it out by changing the code to:

```
for (let i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
    flexibleTokens[i].innerText = data[i] && data[i].token;
    flexibleExamples[i].innerText = data[i] && data[i].example;
}
```

It worked! But in its place I received a console error of: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerText' of undefined.

No matter what I do I receive an error but the code works as expected. Any ideas of how to resolve this??

Comment: `let size = data.length;` and `for (let i = 0; i <= size; i++)` aren't fitting together. Arrays have zero-based indexing, hence when `i == size`, you've exceeded the last index. Remove `=` from the condition. If that doesn't fix the error, then the arrays have different lengths, and you've to make their length equal.

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes we need a fresh set of eyes to see the simplest things!!